# C++ DLL not loaded on C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, c++, vstest

I have a C# classe calling a `MyCppDll.dll` (C++ DLL) using DllImport. This works just fine. But when trying to perform UnitTest on the C# class, I keep getting a DLLNotFoundException.

I am already using DeployementItem on my test method and the MyCppDLL is properly copied on the unitTest folder.

This is my C# wrapper class

```
public class CSharpWrapper()
{
    public int CallMyCpp()
    {

        NativeMethods.callCpp();
    }

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport(@"MyCppDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern Int32 callCpp();
    }
}
```

My test class contains this :

```
[TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@"MyCppDLL.dll")]
public void TestMyCpp()
{
   CallMyCpp();
}
```

My C# project as nothing in particular configuration-wise, but it is :

- Framework 4.5.2 (.Net)
- Unsafe code not allowed
- Optimize code is not set

My Cpp dll uses the following code to export the dll function :

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) int32_t callCpp(); }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please also describe in detail - how You configured the C# project to use the C++ dll.